# Perl Moose - How do I filter a type that does not match a parameter and replace it with a default or null value?

Tags: types, attributes, moose

This is the User.pm

```
package User;
use Moose;

has 'name' => (
  is => 'rw',
  isa => 'Str',
  required => 1
);

has 'age' => (
  is => 'rw',
  isa => 'Int',
  required => 1
);

has 'water' => (
  is => 'rw',
  isa => 'Int',
  required => 1,
  default => '2000'
);

no Moose;
1;
```

This is the program that uses the User.pm

```
#!/bin/perl
BEGIN {
  unshift(@INC, '/tmp'); # User.pm ===> /tmp/User.pm
}
use User;

my $rh_params = {
  name => 'Rebecca',
  age => 25,
  water => '2500cc'
};
my $user = User->new($rh_params);
```

After the program execution

```
Attribute (water) does not pass the type constraint because: Validation failed for 'Int' with value 2500cc at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/Moose/Object.pm line 24
    Moose::Object::new('User', 'HASH(0x157fcb8)') called at go.pl line 12
```

I would like to verify that the type does not meet the time, you can use the default value or null value instead, rather than terminate the program.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Since it's required, you can't use _null_ (that would be `undef` in Perl). You could use a coercion with a custom type to go from the `2500cc` to `2500`. But that's about it.